# Send Javascript object to Rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Using Rails 4 and native Javascript (vanilla).

I have the following Ajax call, which returns the `place` object:

```
// place.js
function addPlace(place) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(place));
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.places_path %>", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", CSRF.token());
  xhr.send("place=" + JSON.stringify(place));
}
```

In the `console.log(JSON.stringify(place))`, I get the following JSON:

```
{"name":"San Francisco","url":"https://maps.google.com/?q=San+Francisco,+CA,+USA&ftid=0x80859a6d00690021:0x4a501367f076adff","utc_offset":-480,"vicinity":"San Francisco","html_attributions":[]}
```

This params is sent to a Rails controller:

```
# places_controller.rb
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    abort params[:place].inspect
    @place = Place.find_or_create_by(source_id: params[:source_id])
    @place.save
    head :ok
  end
end
```

In the line `abort params[:place].inspect`, instead of showing the whole load, it only shows:

```
"{"name":"San Francisco","url":"https://maps.google.com/?q=San+Francisco,+CA,+USA"
```

The `url` gets stripped off because of the `&` in `&ftid=0x80859a6d00690021:0x4a501367f076adff`.

**Questions**

How should I properly pass a Javascript object (preferably Hash) to Rails controller so that I can properly save it in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(place))
```